Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef') in Drawer from @material-tailwind/react
I'm new to @material-tailwind/react
I want to use Drawer in my ongoing create-react-app project.
I followed this guide.
But I got this error:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useRef')

Any advice would be appreciated.
Thank you.
I created a new project for testing according to this guide.
In tailwind.config.js:
import withMT from "@material-tailwind/react/utils/withMT";

 
module.exports = withMT({
  content: [
    "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
});

In index.jsx:
...
import {ThemeProvider} from '@material-tailwind/react'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider>
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
 </React.StrictMode>
);

In App.jsx:
import { Drawer, Button } from "@material-tailwind/react";

export default function App() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <>
      <Button onClick={() => setOpen(true)}>Open Drawer</Button>
      <Drawer open={open} onClose={() => setOpen(false)}>
        <h1>Drawer Content</h1>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  )
}

And got the error above.

I had a similar issue, and it was resolved by downgrading React from 18.3.1 to version 18.2.0. You might want to check the React version you're using

Hi, @rooklee.
Thank you for your answer.
Downgrading the react version to 18.2.0 solved the issue perfectly.
Awesome!!!
